# magento product imports, need an alternative solution

Tags: magento, magmi

I have to import 30.000 products into magento shop and it takes ages. I'm doing that for a week now and I'm only 20% down, it hangs up 20 times a day, it's impossible. I tried to use Magmi (open source solution) and it did work doing everything in seconds, but products don't show on the website, no matter what I tried I just hit a dead end.

Is there any other way to import the products faster into magento? Preferably free solution.

P.S. I run it on a dedicated server, core 2 duo, 4 gb of ram.

Comment: have you reindex after magmi's import? it's working nice for me

Comment: I have the same problem, even with a little more than 1 thousand products (configurable + simple) import is pretty slow. magmi currently doesn't support configurable products, does it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its strange that magmi is not working for you.There are some third party applications to upload products.

- [Magento Extension](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/bolasevich/extension/1894/custom-bulk-product-import-+-export-with-tier-pricing--product-custom-options--configurable-products--bundle-products--grouped-products--downloadable)
- http://www.mag-manager.com/
- http://www.unirgy.com/products/urapidflow/

I never worked with any of the above.So I am not sure how fast these are

Comment: I assume Magmi is the only free solution then, huh?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following extension to import/export your product with images/attributes/categories/customoptions e.t.c. http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/catalog/product/view/id/15862/

You can import more then 50K product at once.